# int A[n] is allocated on STACK or on HEAP?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

If you executed the following lines:

```
    void dummy () {
     int n;
     scanf ("%d", &n);
     int A[n];
    }
```

Will array A be alocated on STACK or on HEAP?

Comment: That's a compiler extension (unless you're compiling with `-std=c++1y` with Clang or something). Read the documentation for it.

Comment: Could you post a link on that?

Comment: @Eduardo: It entirely depends which compiler you're using, since (until next year) it's a non-standard compiler-dependent feature. Here's a link for GCC, to save you a couple of seconds of googling: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Answer (score 5):

Is this supposed to be a C or C++ question?

Note that your array declaration is formally illegal in C++. It is illegal to use non-constant expressions to specify array size in array declaration.

Assuming your C++ compiler supports this declaration (borrowing this feature from C language), `A` is a local array object. It is allocated in the same way as any other local object declared with no linkage, i.e. with automatic storage duration ("on stack" in your terminology).